# Xen libvirt access for non-root user

Tags: xen, d-bus, libvirt, polkit

I've installed Xen and libvirt on a CentOS 6.6 machine. All the tools (virt-manager, virsh etc) work perfectly as root (directly or via sudo) but I cannot allow another user to connect (failed to connect/DBus error).

**My Configuration**

I followed the procedure for allowing user access by creating a group and allowing this through polkit so I've:

```
groupadd virtadmin
usermod -a -G virtadmin davec
```

I also added myself to the KVM group (a suggestion found somewhere). The group is created and I'm in it as id outputs:

```
uid=500(davec) gid=500(davec) groups=500(davec),36(kvm),501(virtadmin)
```

To allow this in polkit I added the file /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-libvert-remote-access.pkla content:

```
Remote libvirt SSH access]
Identity:unix-group:virtadmin
Action:org.libvirt.unix.manage
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

After this didn't work some googling told me that newer polkit versions (yum tells me I have 0.96) use a rules-based approach so I've also created a folder /etc/polkit-1/rules.d and added the file 80-libvirt-manage.rules containing:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "org.libvirt.unix.manage" && 
  subject.local && 
  subject.active && 
  subject.isInGroup("virtadmin")) {
      return polkit.Result.YES;
  }
});
```

Now it may be that there is some problem with these but I can't find a log or any way it seems to test/verify/watch them.

So, according to the docs I've found, with that setup user davec should be able to access libvirt and run virsh or virt-manager.

**The Error**

```
[davec@polar rules.d]$ virsh -c xen:///
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: internal error: DBus support not compiled into this binary
```

This is exactly the same error virt-manager gives when I try and connect.

Most of the online info about the DBus error refers to a problem with the hypervisor running/anyone connecting however root connects perfectly.

```
[davec@polar rules.d]$ sudo virsh -c xen:///
Welcome to virsh, the virtualization interactive terminal.
```

Exactly the same applies for SSH connections (which isn't surprising as SSH just tunnels I believe when you use a xen+ssh URI), root works non-root but group added user doesn't.

No doubt it's something simple and I'm being an idiot but... after a few days of Google not being my friend; any help truly appreciated.

**The Answer**

See below for c4f4t0r's correct (and accepted) answer which wins the bounty but just for info of anyone reading this it turns out to be **nothing to do with polkit** which doesn't appear to be configured/compiled/working with my libvirtd.

Was an in-built permissions (socket permissions) issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do in this way:

in `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf`

```
unix_sock_group = "libvirt"
unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"
auth_unix_rw = "none"
```

After that restart the libvirtd daemon

Comment: You know I thought I'd tried this! And I had apart from the auth_unix_rw line. Turns out that libvirt isn't using polkit at all to control access!! Collect your well-deserved bounty.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
unix_sock_group = "libvirt"
unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"
unix_sock_dir = "/var/run/libvirt"
auth_unix_rw = "none"
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! While this snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.